Project Euler #1: Multiples of 3 and 5 not working with big number
I wrote this mathematical solution to problem #1 from "Project Euler" which is to compute the sum of all multiples of 3 or 5 below some input value n, but for some reason as the input gets very very high the results are slightly incorrect. What is the problem?
def sec_sol(n):
    last_num_3=(n-1)-((n-1)%3)
    last_num_5=(n-1)-((n-1)%5)
    last_num_15 = (n-1)-((n-1)%15)
    sums_of_3=((3+last_num_3)/2)*math.floor(last_num_3/3)
    sums_of_5=((5+last_num_5)/2)*math.floor(last_num_5/5)
    sums_of_15=((15+last_num_15)/2)*math.floor(last_num_15/15)
    return int(sums_of_3 + sums_of_5 - sums_of_15)


why don't you print out the values of these variables for cases that don't work and see for yourself?

The real question here is why are you using floor() if you want an exact result?

Please clearly explain the task, expected result and actual result. Don’t expect us to know all Euler problems by heart or require us to look them up.

Your code is pretty good — you've figured out that you don't need to loop to compute these sums, applied the inclusion-exclusion principle, and the mathematical formulae you've figured out are correct. No doubt your solution passes the test for project Euler (where n=1000).
But — you're using floating point, which in Python will typically mean 64-bit floating point, which will typically mean 53 bits of precision.
If your input is large enough, this causes accuracy to be lost. For example, when n=183785194 (which I believe is the smallest input value for which your code gives the wrong answer) then just printing some intermediate values out we can see the inaccuracy:
n = 183785194
last_num_3 = 183785193
last_num_5 = 183785190
last_num_15 = 183785190
sums_of_3 = 5629499619567138.0 (correct = 5629499619567138)
sums_of_5 = 3377699698226205.0 (correct = 3377699698226205)
sums_of_15 = 1125899960670465.0 (correct = 1125899960670465)
sums_of_3 + sums_of_5 = 9007199317793344.0 (correct = 9007199317793343) <<<<<
result = 7881299357122879.0 (correct=7881299357122878)

You can see your code is correctly computing sums_of_3, sums_of_5 and sums_of_15 for this n, but the result is off by one. That's because sums_of_3 + sums_of_5 isn't representable in a floating point number in Python, which you can see in the lowest decimal place: the correct result is odd and bigger than 2^53 (53 being the number of bits of precision in Python's floating point), which is 9007199254740992.
You can fix your program by using (exact) integer arithmetic, which you can do by moving the "divide by 2" to the end of your expressions when you're computing the sums where it's guaranteed never to round. Note that // is Python's integer division operator.
last_num_3=(n-1)-((n-1)%3)
last_num_5=(n-1)-((n-1)%5)
last_num_15 = (n-1)-((n-1)%15)
sums_of_3=(3+last_num_3)*last_num_3//6
sums_of_5=(5+last_num_5)*last_num_5//10
sums_of_15=(15+last_num_15)*last_num_15//30


Thanks a lot this answers my question exactly❤️

I can see a missing step in your solution: the returned value. After running your function, it works as expected. Consider the following return value:
return sums_of_3 + sums_of_5 - sums_of_15

This makes sense because multiples of 15 include duplicate numbers for both 3 and 5, so we're adding the number twice and need to remove one instance of it.

Yes, the code is missing this line, but the question is asking why the result is not correct for large input values. I fixed the code in the question to include the missing return.

Working with floating-point numbers can lead to small deviations due to the way information is stored in memory. You can observe this with a simple division. Try the following in Python, and you'll notice that working with these numbers later may result in unexpected behavior. Example: "print(10/3)" outputs 3.3333333333333335.

If you have an answer to the question as-asked, it should be in your answer rather than in a note.

@emmanuelFV that's a very chatgpt-sounding comment

Hi @harold, I don't have enough experience in English rather than formal English for work, I didn't meant to sound like a robot. I can ensure that the answer comes from my own ideas.

Floating-point numbers can represent a wide range of integers (wider than int in C for example), and in many contexts are guaranteed to give exact results (for example, this code in the question is guaranteed to produce exact results for inputs that aren't in the hundreds of millions or larger). Here the problem isn't "small deviations" like in your example of 10/3, it's that large integers aren't exactly representable. Maybe that's why harold suggested chatgpt -- your comment was a generic comment about floating point numbers rather than grounded in the question.
